# Is it legal to electronically sign a rental lease in South Australia?

Tags: rental-property, residential-lease, australia, signature

is it legal to 'electronically sign' a lease / bond arrangement?

https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/legality/global/australia states that it's not legal for "some property transactions in South Australia (Law of Property Act 1936 (SA) s26)"

http://www7.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/sa/consol_act/lopa1936198/s26.html

disposition: http://www7.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/sa/consol_act/lopa1936198/s7.html#disposition

conveyance: http://www7.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/sa/consol_act/lopa1936198/s7.html#conveyance

which says lease?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

A lease is an "interest in land" and falls under s26 of the Law of Property Act which Docusign states is not "typically appropriate".

I'm not sure why they say that because on the face of it there seems to be nothing in s26 that conflicts with the [Electronic Communications Act 2000](http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdb/au/legis/sa/consol_act/eca2000270/) – maybe they know of some case law they are not telling us.